# Web API URL design and implementation

Tags: deployment, routes, asp.net-web-api

it is quite common to see advice about API url design, where URLs are on the "/api/v1/resource" format, and then when the API changes, we could change to /api/v2 etc.

Now, this must be implemented somehow. There are a number of options:

- deploy the project at the root of the web server, and let the routing rules take care of handling the /api/v1 part
- deploy the project in a /api/ subfolder (virtual directory), routing rules take care of the /v1, /v2 etc. parts, but are not aware of the /api/ portion of the URLs.
- deploy the project in a /api/v1 subfolder (virtual directory). A new version of the API is a new project altogether, deployed separately. The project deals strictly with the resources as a root concept, but is generally not aware of the /api/vX part.

So, which method would you pick, and why?

Regards,
Daníel

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed my project at the root of the sub-folder and let my routing rules handle the versioning routes. I prefer to have my implementation with as little dependence on my hosting environment as possible in case I want to deploy to an environment that does not support my method of implementation.

[SDammann.WebApi.Versioning](https://github.com/Sebazzz/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning) is the solution I used to achieve this in one of my applications.

However [ASP.NET and Web Tools for Visual Studio 2013 Release](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) will make this even easier.